# WCF: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android, asp.net, json, wcf

i am trying to call WCF service from android client and i got `End of input at character 0 of`
error. the service working fine when i tested it with the WCF Client Test but when i tried it in android client, it didnt and the End of input error generated ... i dont know what i am missing ..

so here is my code

EmployeeInfo.svc

```
namespace EmployeeServices
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "EmployeeInfo" in code, svc and config file together.



        public class EmployeeInfo : IEmployeeInfo
        {
            public Employee GetEmployee(int employeeId)
            {
                Employee employeeInfo = GetEmployees(employeeId).Where(employee => employee.EmployeeId == employeeId).FirstOrDefault();
                return employeeInfo;
            }

            private List<Employee> GetEmployees(int employeeId)
            {

                return new List<Employee> {
                    new Employee { EmployeeId = 11, FirstName = "Waqas", LastName = "Yousuf", Address="A-175 Block 1" , BloodGroup = "B+" },
                    new Employee { EmployeeId = 22, FirstName = "Moiz", LastName = "Ahmed", Address="B-176 Block 2" , BloodGroup = "O-" },
                    new Employee { EmployeeId = 33, FirstName = "Waqas", LastName = "Raza", Address="C-177 Block 3" , BloodGroup = "A+" },
                    new Employee { EmployeeId = 44, FirstName = "Yasir", LastName = "Amin", Address="D-178 Block 4" , BloodGroup = "AB+" },
                    new Employee { EmployeeId = 55, FirstName = "Adeel", LastName = "Ali", Address="E-179 Block 5" , BloodGroup = "B+" } };
            }
        }
    }
```

IEmployeeInfo.cs

```
namespace EmployeeServices
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IEmployeeInfo" in both code and config file together.

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://services.example.com")]
    public interface IEmployeeInfo
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetEmployee/{employeeId}",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Employee GetEmployee(int employeeId);

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="EmployeeService.EmployeeInfo">
        <endpoint kind="webHttpEndpoint"
        contract="EmployeeService.IEmployeeInfo" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Android Method

```
try {
            String SERVICE_URI = "http://192.168.1.4:1234/Employeeinfo.svc";

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URI + "/GetEmployee/11");

            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);


            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

            JSONObject Emp = new JSONObject(new String(buffer));

            // Populate text fields
            ed1.setText(Emp.getString("Address"));
            ed2.setText(Emp.getString("BloodGroup"));
            ed3.setText(Emp.getString("EmployeeId"));
            ed4.setText(Emp.getString("FirstName"));
            ed5.setText(Emp.getString("LastName"));



        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  lblStatus.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
```

i am working for days to learn how i could call WCF service from android application and i am tucking here ... please help

Comment: i am calling it from android cliend and i dont know if the problem in the client or the server

Comment: where u get this eror? is it catch of the client? End of input at character 0 of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just increase the size of this value as 6553600 shown on the image.
[image]

```
WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetEmployee/{employeeId}",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
Method="GET",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Comment: where should i add Method="GET"

Comment: Error 1 'System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGetAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Method'

Comment: i removed the Method="GET" and i got new error >> value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSON Object

Comment: your service has no defects. thatsthe problm in your client side. check whether the object value is retrieved from the service to your ResponseEntity

Comment: felix thanQ for your help .. i fixed it , the problem was in the web.config file